# Cannot Delete Mongo Service and App Due To Error Code 10001

Tags: mongodb, ibm-cloud

Attempting to issue `cf d` against the US South Bluemix node and I am getting the following error:

```
$ cf d myconf2014

Really delete the app myconf2014?> y
Deleting app myconf2014 in org <redacted> / space dev as <redacted>...
FAILED
Server error, status code: 500, error code: 10001, message: Service broker error: instance_id <redacted> not found
```

How do I get that fixed?

Comment: This post did not include the Bluemix tag so I just added it. The tag will give the post much more attention.

Comment: Can you open up ticket with our support team? To open a support ticket, go to https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#support

Answer (score 0):

Your best option here is to open a ticket with the support team as they'll have to help you remove this service instance. IBM.biz/bluemixsupport